# PHP Determining intersection between arrays within multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, intersection, array-intersect

I have a multidimensional array containing three arrays and an array of id's within each. Here is what it looks like:

```
$data = array(
    'first' => array(1,2,3,4,5,6),
    'second' => array(1,2,3),
    'third' => array(1,2,5,6)
);
```

What I'd like to do is run an intersection on all three and end up with the result of an array, in this example, would be `array(1,2)`

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$newArray = array_values(call_user_func_array("array_intersect", $data));
```

`array_intersect` returns the identical values of all the arrays passed, so you can pass the entries of `$data` as arguments to it. `array_values` is needed for reindexing as the keys won't be changed (not necessary, but helpful when you use the resulting array in a `for` loop).

Answer (score 2):

using `array_reduce` and `array_intersect`.

```
$v = array_values($data);
$r = array_slice($v, 1);
$result = array_reduce($r, 'array_intersect', $v[0]);
var_dump($result);
```

Here is a one-liner.

```
array_reduce(array_slice($data, 0, -1), 'array_intersect', end($data));
```

Comment: @raina here to you. Added a one-liner

Comment: I saw that, ok. ) What I yet to see is how this is better than using `call_user_func_array`, though.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Nice solution, but sadly array_reduce needs an initial value here. This reduces a bit the beauty of the solution...

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im but the array_slice is unnecessary as an intersection with the same array won't change anything.

Comment: @bwoebi it wont change the result. But it'll execute `array_intersect` on same elements twice. This was prevented by using `array_slice`.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im This is what I meant: it is not necessary. And there's no performance impact as array_slice (contrary to array_splice) will duplicate the entries of the array.

Answer (score 0):

what about the following approach:

```
$comp = null;
foreach ($data as $arr) {
  if ($comp === null) {
    $comp = $arr;
    continue;
  } else {
    $comp = array_intersect($comp, $arr);
  }
}
//$comp no contains all the unique values;
```

btw: works with any count of $data except $data = null

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this is with array_reduce:

```
function process($result, $item) {
    return is_null($result) ? $item : array_intersect($result, $item);
}
$result = array_reduce($data, 'process');
```

Or use array_reduce with an anonymous function like this:

```
$result = array_reduce($data, function($result, $item) {
    return is_null($result) ? $item : array_intersect($result, $item);
});
```

This last solution has the advantage of not needing to reference a function (built-in or otherwise) using a string containing the function name.